# React Signalr Access State Variable

Tags: reactjs, signalr.client

So I am trying to update my state when a new message comes in from signalr, but when console log the state variable, its empty.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const results = await myApiCall();

  setPosts(results);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  websocket.connection.off(‘OnPostCreated’, (data) => {
    console.log(posts);
  });

  websocket.connection.on(‘OnPostCreated’, (data) => {
    console.log(posts);
  });

}, [posts]);
```

The response I get from the console log is an empty array. I know posts is not empty as I see the posts on my page. If I replace the console log with `setPosts(data)`, it replaces all the posts with the one coming back from signalr. Thoughts on why inside the on callback that posts is showing empty vs being populated? Thanks

Comment: How many times does your console.log() log. I think you have multiple event handlers here.

Comment: Just once, and it happens when the event happens

Comment: @TusharShahi is there a way to see if it is?

Comment: The first useEffect. I forgot to add await in front, but that does not fix it

Comment: I am assuming there must be an async too. Add that to the question, to prevent unneeded comments. Also, can you put a console.log() in your main body of second useEffect to see the number of times it is called.

Comment: If I put a console log in 2nd useEffect above the websocket line, its called twice

Comment: Yes there is an async method, I just shorten for code example

Comment: Think it is safe to assume in the two times useEffect is called, the first time posts is an empty array and second time it has the data. You can confirm that. Maybe your socket.connection.on event is called before the new posts state is set. That is why it shows the old value of state.

Comment: I updated post to show that I do an off before the on to try to avoid multiple listeners.

Comment: @jrock2004 did you figure it out yet? I have the same issue at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround I used when I encountered this issue. I am still looking for a proper solution.

You can use a separate state variable and update it in the handler callback. In this case the previous state does not matter since you're only updating the variable and not accessing it in the callback. A useEffect can then be used to track this change and make the necessary changes to the posts array which should include the data you set earlier.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [newPostReceived, setNewPostReceived] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const results = await myApiCall();
  setPosts(results);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // check for undefined
  if(newPostReceived){
    let newPosts=[...posts, newPostReceived]
    setPosts(newPosts);
  }
}, [newPostReceived]);

useEffect(() => {
  websocket.connection.off(‘OnPostCreated’, (data) => {
    console.log(posts);
  });

  websocket.connection.on(‘OnPostCreated’, (data) => {
    setNewPostReceived(data);
  });

}, [posts]);
```

Comment: This looked hopeful, but SignalR appears to overwrite the value before it can be consumed so in a rapid sequence of messages this gets only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a flaw of signalR.  Here's the function from `HubConnection` when a message comes in:

```
private _invokeClientMethod(invocationMessage: InvocationMessage) {
    const methods = this._methods[invocationMessage.target.toLowerCase()];
    if (methods) {
        try {
            methods.forEach((m) => m.apply(this, invocationMessage.arguments));
        } catch (e) {
            this._logger.log(LogLevel.Error, `A callback for the method ${invocationMessage.target.toLowerCase()} threw error '${e}'.`);
        }

        if (invocationMessage.invocationId) {
            // This is not supported in v1. So we return an error to avoid blocking the server waiting for the response.
            const message = "Server requested a response, which is not supported in this version of the client.";
            this._logger.log(LogLevel.Error, message);

            // We don't want to wait on the stop itself.
            this._stopPromise = this._stopInternal(new Error(message));
        }
    } else {
        this._logger.log(LogLevel.Warning, `No client method with the name '${invocationMessage.target}' found.`);
    }
}
```

The method is called by the `apply` method, which then sets the `this` variable to the current connection you have.  It will be impossible to get an updated values of a state variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know signalr but I am seeing issue in your useEffect hook. You are unbinding `OnPostCreated` in the same time when you binding it to get the data. So, it could be your issue. You should unbind the method on clean up:

```
useEffect(() => {
  websocket.connection.on('OnPostCreated', (data) => {
    console.log(posts);
  });
  return () => {
    websocket.connection.off('OnPostCreated'); // don't expect data
  }

}, [posts]);
```

Comment: You should be able to log the data, let me know if you need any help further.

Comment: Ah, just noticed it's a year old post. :D

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at react-use-signalr this will take care about your states and hooks ;)
https://github.com/pguilbert/react-use-signalr

Comment: This is more like comment,  More about [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)